# PayPal SSL VeriSign G5 root certificate and No trusted certificate was found

Tags: security, ssl, paypal, certificate

I have Symantec CA in trust store. I am getting "No trusted certificate was found" error during the handshake with PayPal server.I have seen the following in PayPal developer site

> If you receive a handshake error (e.g. “No trusted certificate
>   found”), check the merchant keystone to see if the PayPal VeriSign G5
>   root certification is present.

Does that mean I need to have VeriSign CA in trust store?

> https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-ssl-certificate-changes

My understanding is Symantec CA is root to VeriSign. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As the documentation advices, you need to add it to the trust store.